# Method to access class members by item numbers

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry for newbie question.  I'm new to VBA class.

I created a cRanges class which is basically a collection of another custom object.  And I defined a Item method for it.  But I couldn't understand why the Item method of cRanges class didn't work?

Here's my code:

```
' CLASS MODULE - cRange
' Member variables
Private m_Low As String
Private m_High As String

' Properties
Property Get low() As String
    low = m_Low
End Property

Property Get high() As String
    high = m_High
End Property

Property Let low(s As String)
    m_Low = s
End Property

Property Let high(s As String)
    m_High = s
End Property

------------------

' CLASS MODULE - cRanges
' Member variables
Private m_Ranges As New Collection
Private r As New cRange

' Methods
Public Sub Add(r As cRange)
    m_Ranges.Add r
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(r As cRange)
    m_Ranges.Remove r
End Sub

Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = m_Ranges.Count
End Function

Public Function Item(i As Integer) As cRange
    If i > 0 And i <= m_Ranges.Count Then Set Items = m_Ranges.Item(i)
End Function

--------------------

Sub main()

Dim r As New cRange
Dim rr As New cRanges

r.low = "2"
r.high = "9"

rr.Add r

Debug.Print r.low
Debug.Print r.high

Debug.Print rr.Count
Debug.Print rr.Item(1).high '<-- Object variable or with block variable not set

End Sub
```

Thanks!
...................................................................................

Comment: What is `Contains = False`?

Comment: What is `Items`? I don't see it in the code...

Comment: Your function is `Item` but you're setting `Items` to return a value.  And your Remove method needs an `index` parameter (numeric index or string key) not an object-type argument.

Comment: Thank you Tim!  I gotta get a better glasses!

Comment: for what's in your code you don't need `cRanges` Class at all and you may just go with a plain`Collection` object